# Split a List into several Lists based on criteria using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of integers, which I would like to split into 2 or more lists based upon meeting a certain criteria.  For example:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
myList.Add(100);
myList.Add(200);
myList.Add(300);
myList.Add(400);
myList.Add(200);
myList.Add(500);
```

I would like to split the list into several lists, each of which contains all items which total <= 600.  In the above, it would then result in 3 separate List objects.

- List 1 would contain 100, 200 300
- List 2 would contain 400, 200
- List 3 would contain 500

Ideally, I'd like it to be a single LINQ statement.

Comment: What have you tried and why does it have to be in linq or even a single linq statement?

Comment: What have you tried? What did that code do? How was that _specifically_ different from what you wanted it to do? Along with answers to those questions, please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) supporting those answers. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Thats not possible with single linq statement but one line linq. Or you have to implement your own extention methot for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although doable, this is an excellent example of what LINQ is **not** for. Check yourself.

Having

```
var myList = new List<int> { 100, 200, 300, 400, 200, 500, };
int maxSum = 600;
```

"Pure" LINQ (the power of [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548744(v=vs.100).aspx))

```
var result = myList.Aggregate(
    new { Sum = 0, List = new List<List<int>>() },
    (data, value) =>
    {
        int sum = data.Sum + value;
        if (data.List.Count > 0 && sum <= maxSum)
            data.List[data.List.Count - 1].Add(value);
        else
            data.List.Add(new List<int> { (sum = value) });
        return new { Sum = sum, List = data.List };
    },
    data => data.List)
    .ToList();
```

A normal (non LINQ) implementation of the above

```
var result = new List<List<int>>();
int sum = 0;
foreach (var value in myList)
{
    if (result.Count > 0 && (sum += value) <= maxSum)
        result[result.Count - 1].Add(value);
    else
        result.Add(new List<int> { (sum = value) });
}
```

For completeness (and some fun), a "Hackish" LINQ (the power of closures and C# operators)

```
int sum = 0, key = -1;
var result = myList.GroupBy(x => key >= 0 && (sum += x) <= maxSum ? key : ++key + (sum = x) * 0, (k, e) => e.ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to your problem. I am not sure if that is the best case solver but it will surely do the job:

```
List<int> First = myList.Where(x => x <= 300).ToList();
List<int> Second = myList.Where(x => x == 400 || x == 200).ToList();
List<int> Third = myList.Where(x => x == 500).ToList();
```

It does query through the list and checks for values that meets the requirements then it will convert IEnumerable into the List.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want for a list any size but maybe not as short as you are looking for. You would have to write a LINQ extension method to shorten it but then it become a bit more complicated.

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
myList.Add(100);
myList.Add(200);
myList.Add(300);
myList.Add(400);
myList.Add(200);
myList.Add(500);

var result = new List<List<int>>();
var skip = 0;
while (skip < myList.Count)
{
    var sum = 0;
    result.Add(myList.Skip(skip).TakeWhile(x =>
    {
        sum += x;
        return sum <= 600;
    }).ToList());
    skip += result.Last().Count();
}
```